# Creating a PDF File Based on Text Entry made in text fields by user

Tags: html, jspdf

I want to create a PDF file along with the text entered by user in text fields(textarea and input type=text).I have an iframe which renders my template consisting of labels and input text fields.Now, I am able to correctly render this template to a PDF file using jspdf.But I want the template along with the user entered text values to be rendered in the PDF file.Please note that I dont want to change the templates html() permanently.Is there a way I can clone a temporary html and then render it via jspdf.Also note that jspdf will only print text within text nodes, which means that it will not print the values of textareas and the like. Example:

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <!-- This is printed as the element contains a textnode -->        
    <li>Print me!</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <!-- This is not printed because jsPDF doesn't deal with the value attribute -->
    <input type="textarea" value="Please print me, too!">
  </div>
</body>
```

I use the below code to generate pdf from the iframe...

```
    var body = $("#DispTemp").contents().find('body');
              var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
              // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
              // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
              // var content = document.getElementById('DispTemp').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

              source = body[0].innerHTML;

              // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
              // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
              // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
              // (class, of compound) at this time.
              specialElementHandlers = {
                  // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
                  '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                      // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                      return true
                  }
              };
              margins = {
                  top: 80,
                  bottom: 60,
                  left: 40,
                  width: 522
              };
              // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
              // 'inches' in this case
              pdf.fromHTML(
source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
margins.left, // x coord
margins.top, { // y coord
    'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
},

function (dispose) {
    // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
    //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
    pdf.save('Test.pdf');
                  }, margins);
```

Besides as an option I have also use html2canvas and casper libraries.But there is a problem of text distortion with them..